How to fix "multi level implicit pointer conversion" warning in clang-tidy?
I have some legacy code that reads like this:
bool has_attribute(int kvidx) const {
    void* v = nullptr;
    int flag = 0;
    MPI_Comm_get_attr(impl_, kvidx, &v, &flag);
    return flag != 0;
}

The third argument of MPI_Comm_get_attr takes a void**.
CORRECTION: … it takes void*, but it is void** semantically according to the function documentation. This is the true origin of the warning.
This code now is giving a clang-tidy warning bugprone-multi-level-implicit-pointer-conversion.
https://releases.llvm.org/18.1.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone/multi-level-implicit-pointer-conversion.html
Clang-tidy recommends: "multilevel pointer conversion from 'char **' to 'void *', please use explicit cast"
How do I apply this "explicit cast"?
I tried with MPI_Comm_get_attr(impl_, kvidx, static_cast<void**>(&v), &flag); but clang is still complaining.
To be clear, the code is correct AFAIK, I am trying to follow clang-tidy recommendation (without suppressing the warning)

Clang is right you have multiple issues even . And you have at least one case of undefined behavior:  flag is NOT initialized. And then read the documentation here
https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Comm_get_attr.html , seems you can use nullptr for the 3rd argument if flag is false.

@PepijnKramer, thanks for the comment, I initialized the variable to remove this distraction. (I think flag is initialized by the function anyway).

@PepijnKramer that's output values, MPI_Comm_get_attr sets pointer and flag if itis able to retrieve the attribute. "Safe" c++ static check doesn't understand neither such use of pointer ( v is void** but declared as void*), nor return through pass-by-pointer. This requires C-wrapper (not extern "C", a true C code) with C++-friendly interface.

@Swift-FridayPie, if v is of type void*, &v is of type void**, no? (BTW, the clang-tidy warning is not fixed by declaring char* v.)

Sorry all, according to an answer deleted the problem was that I got wrong the argument of the function and that is what the warning is about,

In similar situations, I've used void* vv = &v; and call it by MPI_Comm_get_attr(impl_, kvidx, vv, &flag);

@Eljay but wouldn't Clang-tidy detect the same issue with void* vv = &v; ? (because &v is void** and you assign it to a void*, just like passing it as a void* argument).

@wohlstad • Not sure what clang-tidy will do with that.  The beauty of void* is that it can point to anything.  (Well, const-correctness may get involved.)

@Eljay you are right about void* in general, but here the argument of the function is void* and clang-tidy detected an issue with the conversion of the passed argument (&v which I think is a void**). Anyway - I am not certain what clang-tidy will do with that as well.

@Eljay, Just to confirm that void* vv = &v; or void* vv(&v); still gives the warning. The good is that it isolates the tricky step. All in all, this clang-tidy warning and suppression is very good because forces a comment on a part of the code that is fundamentally tricky.

Clang-tidy is correct from its point of view.
The problem arises from the behavior of the API.
According to the MPI_Comm_get_attr ducumentation, this is the signature of the function:

int MPI_Comm_get_attr(MPI_Comm comm, int comm_keyval, void *attribute_val, int *flag)

The 3rd parameter is a void*, not a void**, so Clang-tidy rightfully detected that a multi-level conversion is needed.
However the MPI_Comm_get_attr ducumentation also states that:

Even though the attr_value argument is declared as void *, it is really the address of a void pointer. See the rationale in the standard for more details.

So you were right to pass &v as an argument.
The only solution I see is to suppress Clang-tidy for this part of the code.

Thanks, I think it is making sense (after much confusion), the problem really the weird C-interface.

I agree. In the beginning when I saw the signature I thought it was a simple mistake, but after reading the documentation again I noticed that note that changes everything ...

I bet there is still a problem with this code, I think what happens is that it is taking the address of a pointer to allocate a the value of the attribute. In that case this could be a memory leak, unless the pointer to the attribute is immediately deleted (free'd to be consistent).

I am not sure, and the documentation does not mention is explicitly. But maybe the function is setting the pointer to point to some statically allocated data. I am not familiar with the API to know for sure. It does mention "the rationale in the standard for more details" but unfortunately I do not know what part it is reffering to.

Yes, it is that. The data is deleted when the keyval is deleted, meanwhile is persistent. https://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Type_delete_attr.html . The standard refers to the MPI standard, which is a document of few hundred pages . https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/

I guess also this means that the problem was with the casting to the argument type really. BTW, this code belongs to this MPI wrapper library of mine: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-mpi3

I am just realizing how common this "note" is. https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Alloc_mem.html

Yes, these are things that are a rarely done (if at all) in modern C++ code, but do exists in legacy C libraries.

I think this is C, but worst. because some extra weirdness introduced by the Fortran  interface provided by the library. If it were pure C, they have actually used void** or char** at least.

@wohlstad this is also normal for nearly every industrial or comm API. E.g. GIS, aerial telemetry, various hardware interfaces, SCADA, etc. data is either persistent or fully managed by library, the "driver" (which in slang means the controlling program) can only request the access to it. Some semblance of that is present in Windows API, but a little with more control.

@alfC I think, possibility of platforms with variable size of pointer (Fortan might be  just one of the cases), it is agreed that void* got always same size. Attributes in C are of type void *. Typically, such an attribute will be a pointer to a structure that contains further information, or a handle to an MPI object. In Fortran, attributes are of type INTEGER. Such attribute can be a handle to an MPI object, or just an integer-valued attribute. (advice to users.)
